# How to check the highest condition by comparing data from one array to another?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I would like to apply discounts according to a given rule:

- If the quantity is greater than 10, apply a 5% discount
- If the quantity is greater than 20, apply a 10% discount
- If the quantity is greater than 30, apply a 15% discount

I have expressed said rule in one array.

But I don't know how to verify that only the highest possible condition is met.

For example, if the amount is greater than 30, apply only 15%.

Any idea how to solve this or improve the logic?

#### Code

```
$rules=array(10=>5, 20=>10, 30=>15);
$qty=array(
    array('qty'=>1, 'price'=>100),
    array('qty'=>2, 'price'=>9),
    array('qty'=>10, 'price'=>54),
    array('qty'=>13, 'price'=>22),
    array('qty'=>21, 'price'=>8),
    array('qty'=>22, 'price'=>999),
    array('qty'=>35, 'price'=>2),
    array('qty'=>50, 'price'=>1),
    
);

print("qty\tprice\tfinalPrice\n");

foreach ($qty as $item) {
    $finalPrice=$item['price'];
    $discount="";

    foreach ($rules as $k=>$v) {
        if($item['qty'] >= $k) {
            $finalPrice= $finalPrice - ($finalPrice * ($v / 100));
            $discount.="*";
        }
    }    
    printf("%s\t%s\t%s%s\n",$item['qty'],$item['price'],$finalPrice,$discount);
}
```

**OutPut:**

```
  qty   price   finalPrice
  1     100     100
  2     9       9
  10    54      51.3*
  13    22      20.9*
  21    8       6.84**
  22    999     854.145**
  35    2       1.4535***
  50    1       0.72675***
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What's the expected output? What have you tried to spot and resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the `$rules` array from the highest key to lowest. This means if we encounter a threshold, we don't need to do anymore iterations for the lower rule:

```php
uksort($rules, fn($a, $b) => $b - $a);
```

You could rework the calculation statement slightly to be more lean, though this is more stylistic tweak:

```php
$finalPrice *= (1 - ($v / 100));
```

For the discount string, I assumed that an asterisk corresponds to a multiple of 10 corresponding to the discount applied:

```php
$discount = str_repeat('*', round($k / 10));
```

Lastly, we `break` inside the `if` since we do not need to process anymore rules for the current item. The saves some iteration cycles.

Putting it all together:

```php
uksort($rules, fn($a, $b) => $b - $a);

print("qty\tprice\tfinalPrice\n");

foreach ($qty as $item) {
    $finalPrice=$item['price'];
    $discount="";

    foreach ($rules as $k=>$v) {
        if($item['qty'] >= $k) {
            $finalPrice= $finalPrice * (1 - ($v / 100));
            $discount = str_repeat('*', round($k / 10));
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\t%s\t%s%s\n",$item['qty'],$item['price'],$finalPrice,$discount);
}
```

Would output:

```
qty price   finalPrice
1   100 100
2   9   9
10  54  51.3*
13  22  20.9*
21  8   7.2**
22  999 899.1**
35  2   1.7***
50  1   0.85***
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Two things are missing:

Since you test with

```
if ($item['qty'] >= $k) {
```

you need to sort the $rules array in descending order by its keys, like this:

```
$rules = [ 10 => 5, 20 => 10, 30 => 15 ];
krsort($rules);
```

The second step is to add a *break* statement to the inner loop:

```
foreach ($rules as $k => $v) {
  if ($item['qty'] >= $k) {
    $finalPrice -= ( $finalPrice * ( $v / 100 ) );
    // $discount .= '*';   
    break;   // Discount found, so stop testing for other discounts
  }
}
```

Now the output will be:

```
1   100 100
2   9   9
10  54  51.3
13  22  20.9
21  8   7.2
22  999 899.1
35  2   1.7
50  1   0.85
```

The line

```
 $discount .= '*';
```

is commented out because it does not make sense anymore. It showed how often a discount was applied. If the purpose is to show the size of the discount – 5 prints: *, 10 prints: **, 15 prints: *** –, then this line would produce that output:

```
 $discount = str_repeat('*', $v / 5);
```